# Facebook app using iframe error

Tags: facebook, iframe

before i used the following code in my facebook app it works. But recently, the chrome browser blocked my content and said it is unsafe code. By any chance anyone can help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>

<center><IFRAME SRC="http://www.XX.com/index.html" WIDTH=660 HEIGHT=700 frameborder="0">

</IFRAME>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you talking about an app within facebook.com (canvas/page tab app)? For those you have to load all of your content via HTTPS, when the user is surfing Facebook via HTTPS. If your `www.XX.com` domain is accessible via HTTPS, then just change the iframe address to `//www.XX.com/…` – that’ll let the browser pick the appropriate protocol automatically. (I assume your app itself, so the main document you’ve shown above, get loaded via HTTPS already – otherwise you would not even see that inside the FB iframe.)

Comment: OK, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are referencing a domain in the iframe other than the one your page is hosted at?  This violates the cross origin framing policy.  This [blog article](http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/) may help shed some light on the issue for you.

Comment: That article is about accessing stuff via JavaScript – and this a completely different matter (and usually referred to as Same Origin Policy). Just displaying content from another domain inside an iframe is no problem in general.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an app within facebook.com (canvas/page tab app)? For those you have to load all of your content via HTTPS, when the user is surfing Facebook via HTTPS.

If your `www.XX.com` domain is accessible via HTTPS, then just change the iframe address to `//www.XX.com/…` – that’ll let the browser pick the appropriate protocol automatically.