# Embedded Youtube video won't play in Facebook app

Tags: facebook, youtube

I'm working on a simple FB app of a type I've done many times before. It works perfectly outside FB but once it's in FB, the youtube embed simply doesn't load.

I pulled the code out into a test file, and it still won't load. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="669" height="391" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/48P1jc5tyTw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

Absolutely nothing displays when this is loaded as an app on a FB page. The FB debugger says "Can't Download    Could not retrieve data from URL."

Any ideas?

Comment: curious, why do you use `application/xhtml+xml` ( XHTML ) as Content Type? Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19324018/188331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the src of the iframe to "https://...".

Since Facebook is served over HTTPS, your browser will block any content from loading on the page that's not over HTTPS too. Fortunately, youtube supports https versions of their URLs.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I've been staring at this code snippet for two hours now. :)